# Linear Algebra problem (linear algebra done right)

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to solve exercise 17 in chapter 3.D of Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right.

Suppose $V$ is finite dimensional and $E$ is a subspace of $L(V)$ such that $ST$ is part of $E$ and $TS$ is part of $E$ for all $S$ part of $L(V)$ and $T$ part of $E$. Prove that $E=0$ or $E=L(V)$.

This is my proof:

Suppose $E$ is not the zero transform.
Let $T$ be part of $E$, and $S$ not part of $E$ but part of $L(V)$.
$ST$ can only be part of $E$, if $S$ can be expressed as a linear sum of the basis of transforms of $E$. (since $ST$ ultimately transforms a vector in $V$ by $S$). Which is a contradiction since $S$ is not part of $E$.

The proof is obvious if $E=0$ (then $T=0$, and $ST=TS=0$, and $ST$, $TS$ are part of $E$).

Am I missing something?
Thanks.

Comment: You should probably define what $L,S,T$ are

Comment: L(V) is all linear operators on V. S and T are linear operators in V. E is a subspace of L(V).

Comment: Can you explain the contradiction "S is not part of E"? It seems like you're missing a step / condition.

Comment: By hypothesis, S is part of L but not part of E.  T part of L AND part of E.
I'm arguing that since ST(v) = S(T(v)) and T(v) is a vector in V, then the only ST way is part of E is if S is part of E, which is a contradiction with the hypothesis. Hence, ST can not be part of E if S is not.

Comment: Right, my (minor) point is that you needed "If $E \neq L(V)$, then there exists $ S \in L(V) - E$..."

Comment: The claim of " $ST$ can only be part of E, *if* $S$ can be expressed as ..." is not true.It might be possible that the range space of $T$ lies within the "kernel" (not quite the right encompassing word) of $S$. E.g. $T= 0 $ satisfies the condition that $T$ is part of $E$, but clearly $ST$ is also part of $E$ for any $S$.

Comment: OK I see your point. All I need to do is chose T such as T~=0, which I of course can do since I excluded the E=0 condition (treated later). Is that correct?

Comment: see here: https://math.solverer.com/library/sheldon_axler/linear_algebra_done_right/exercise_3-d-17?utm_source=stackexchange.com&utm_medium=link

Answer (score 1):

Let $v_1,\dots,v_n$ be a basis of $V$.
Assume that $\mathcal{E}\neq\{0\}$.
Let $T\in\mathcal{E}-\{0\}$.
Let $a_{ij}$ be elements of $\mathbb{F}$ such that
$Tv_1=a_{11}v_1+\dots+a_{n1}v_n$,
$\dots$
$Tv_j=a_{1j}v_1+\dots+a_{nj}v_n$,
$\dots$
$Tv_n=a_{1n}v_1+\dots+a_{nn}v_n$.

Since $T\neq 0$, there exist $k,l\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ such that $a_{kl}\neq 0$.

Let $S_1\in\mathcal{L}(V)$ be a linear map such that
$S_1v_l=\frac{1}{a_{kl}}v_l$,
$S_1v_i=0$ for $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}-\{l\}$.

Let $S_2\in\mathcal{L}(V)$ be a linear map such that
$S_2v_k=v_k$,
$S_2v_i=0$ for $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}-\{k\}$.

Then,
$S_2TS_1v_l=S_2T(\frac{1}{a_{kl}}v_l)=\frac{1}{a_{kl}}S_2Tv_l=\frac{1}{a_{kl}}S_2(a_{1l}v_1+\dots+a_{nl}v_n)=\frac{1}{a_{kl}}a_{kl}v_k=v_k$,
$S_2TS_1v_i=S_2T0=S_20=0$ for $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}-\{l\}$.

Let $i,j\in\{1,\dots,n\}$.

Let $S_3\in\mathcal{L}(V)$ be a linear map such that
$S_3v_j=v_l$,
$S_3v_p=0$ for $p\in\{1,\dots,n\}-\{j\}$.

Let $S_4\in\mathcal{L}(V)$ be a linear map such that
$S_4v_k=v_i$,
$S_4v_p=0$ for $p\in\{1,\dots,n\}-\{k\}$.

Then,
$S_4(S_2TS_1)S_3v_j=S_4(S_2TS_1)v_l=S_4v_k=v_i$,
$S_4(S_2TS_1)S_3v_p=S_4(S_2TS_1)0=S_40=0$ for $p\in\{1,\dots,n\}-\{j\}$.

By the assumption for $\mathcal{E}$, $S_4(S_2TS_1)S_3\in\mathcal{E}$.

So, for any $i,j\in\{1,\dots,n\}$, a linear map $T_{ij}\in\mathcal{L}(V)$ such that $T_{ij}v_j=v_i$ and $T_{ij}v_p=0$ for $p\in\{1,\dots,n\}-\{j\}$ is an element of $\mathcal{E}$.

Since $T_{11},T_{12},\dots,T_{1n},T_{21},T_{22},\dots,T_{2n},\dots,T_{n1},T_{n2},\dots,T_{nn}$ is a basis of $\mathcal{L}(V)$, $\mathcal{E}=\mathcal{L}(V)$.